# Recurrent relation- integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

How to calculate $I_n=\int_{-n}^n \frac{y^n+y^3\cos{y}}{(|y|+1)^{n+2}} dy$? For $n=2k+1$ $I_n=0$, but what for $n=2k$?

I'm stuck with this problem, any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wasn't it an $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty$, by any chance?

Comment: @IvanNeretin No

Comment: Too bad.$\mathstrut$

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem in two ways, by binomial theorem and by substitution $-\frac{1}{y+1}=t$. It is easy to check that $I_n=2\int_0^n (\frac{y}{1+y})\frac{dy}{(y+1)^2}=2\int_0^n (1-\frac{1}{y+1})^n d(\frac{-1}{y+1})$, since the other integral in $I_n$ is zero because $y^3$ is odd, and $\cos{y}, (|y|+1)$ are even functions.